# Copy a file with SCP on Ubuntu 14 with PEM key on both servers

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, copy

I have 2 servers on Amazon AWS. I need to pass a file from A to B.
Both servers have pem keys (different).
I put the pem file of B on A (Is that correct?)
Then tried to do from A:

```
scp -i /tmp/B.pem backup.sql.gz ubuntu@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:bckup.sql.gz
```

I get an error:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   lost connection

Whats the problem?

BTW - I opened port 22 on both

Answer (score 1):

First make sure PEM key permission is correct and not open.

> chmod 400 /tmp/B.pem
>
> scp -r -i /tmp/B.pem backup.sql.gz
>   ubuntu@ec2-XX-XX-XXX-XX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/

This will copy the GZIP file on home directory of ubuntu user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it wrong.
If you want to pass a file from A to B, you need to put the authentication key from A on B. B authenticates a connection from A.

Comment: what the OP calls 'pem key' is actually the ssh private key. What he is doing is correct: he copied the private key of B on A and he's is using it to authenticate on A.

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps try to see if destination folder have write permissions.

Comment: wrong filesystem permissions will not result in errors regarding the public key (except permissions of the .ssh folder of course).